# Business Process Simulator prototype JAVA advice

Tags: jbpm, bpel, business-process-management, bpmn

I have chosen to develop a prototype for a simply business process simulator as a part of my dissertation. I would welcome any/all suggestion and guidance

The objectives of this project is to gain the basic knowledge of software simulation and have a deep understanding of different software models which describe the structural and behavioral characteristics of a business process. The business process can be modeled in BPMN (Business process model and notation) or BPEL (Business process execution language). The deliverable of the project will include a process simulator, along with case studies of various types of business processes.
I would be creating a simulator in JAVA

First of all, do i use BPMN or BPEL for modeling business process ?

Second, is it wise to develop a simulator from scratch or use open source code such as buildap or jBPM and build on that.

Third, Could anyone recommend me a book to learn the types of business processes or in other words, the categories and modeling of business models depending on the kind of process ( the best you know of ), and also for java simulation.

Answer (score 0):

How about joining the jBPM project and join the efforts that are being done around simulation?
Maciej is now working on that topic as we speak, so I'm sending him the link to your question so you can stay in touch.
CHeers

Answer (score 0):

As salaboy said, we started to provide simulation support for jBPM5 which in general is based on alternative flows of the process (initially most likely will be extended). If you like to get in touch just step by at jbpm IRC channel so we could talk more about it (chat.freenode.net#jbpm)